# What am I supposed to do in this task?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, floating-point

> We got two (identical) functions given
>
> $$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-1$$
>
> $$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}$$
>
> Calculate the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for each $x=\frac{1}{2^i},
> i=1,...,25$ using a program of your choice (so we don't need to do it
>   by hand). Do it once with single and once with double precision
>   floating-point format and compare the results with each other.

So my question is about the

> Calculate the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for each $x=\frac{1}{2^i},
> i=1,...,25$

So let me make an example for $x=1: f(1) = \sqrt{1^2+1}-1= \sqrt{2}-1$

Now they want this in single and double precision floating point format, correct?

And then I do the same for $x=2,...25$, right?

And then my other question

> compare the results with each other

Do I compare single and double precision results or compare results of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

I hope you can clarify it for me, the teacher just ignored my question as it seems :(

Comment: You will have different results for each type (long double or double or float) and each function. And what what do you want to do with that result? Or question is why do you have different results?

Comment: Comparing $f$ and $g$, first with single, then for double. Then wonder wich formula gives better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And then I do the same for $x=2,...25$, right?

No, that's not what it says. It says do the same for $i=2\ldots 25$ for $x=\frac{1}{2^i}$. So $1/2$, $1/4$, etc. The smaller your number grows, the more important the errors in floating point arithmetic will become.

> Do it once with single and once with double precision floating-point format and compare the results with each other.

This makes it sound as if the entire point of the exercise is to compare the floating point results, so as to see how different expressions can accumulate error differently.

There is no point in comparing the "actual" results because we already know they will be identical.

Comment: Ohh I just realized then I will end up with many results. $25$ results for $f(x)$ in single, another $25$ for double. Then the same amount for $g(x)$. In total $100$ results, really?!

Comment: Yes, but the interesting changes happen from $k=11$ to $12$ for single and from $k=25$ to $26$ for double precision floats, thus it is unclear why the task stops at $k=25$.

Comment: @cnmesr Don't you mean $50$? And even if it were $100$, why would that be a problem? Using a computer it would take less than a minute to generate thousands of results. You *are* writing $f$ and $g$ as functions into a program as suggested, right?

Comment: @LutzL Perhaps the problem/lesson was developed under an older generation of computer where machine epsilon was larger? It's a good suggestion to go a little further than $25$ to see what happens.

Comment: @rschwieb They are looking for single and double precision. We have two functions. $2 \cdot 25$ single and $2 \cdot 25$ double. Or I don't need to do it for both functions since they are identical?  If that's the case, I don't see why the teacher gave us two functions.

Comment: What program would you suggest? So far I have never worked with maths and program (except for a regular calculator :p).

Comment: @cnmesr When in school, we had access to MATLAB to do an assignment like this. But I'm sure any open source CAS would be fine (I do not have much experience with them.) Whatever you use, you just need to be able to specify the precision of the input variable. I'm sure others can make more better recommendations than I can.

Comment: @cnmesr Oh yes, I didn't notice the two precisions. $100$ results yes, but really only two trials that yield $50$ differences. It's the differences in results that you care about. Intuitively you'll expect larger differences of $g$ from the true value since its computation aggregates more error.

Comment: @LutzL Can you recommend me some good tool that will do that calculation? I assume you used one because you quickly saw the "interesting changes". I should use one because they want me to calculate $100$ solutions anyway :o

Comment: No tool, the only thing needed to know is that the mantissa lengths are 23 and 52 for single and double float. Thus $\sqrt{1+(2^{-11})^2}$ resp. $\sqrt{1+(2^{-25})^2}$ still have one mantissa bit set per $\sqrt{1+x}=1+x/2+O(x^2)$, while the next ones $\sqrt{1+(2^{-12})^2}$ resp. $\sqrt{1+(2^{-26})^2}$ evaluate to $1$, as the next bit in the square root would be at binary position $25$ resp. $53$ after the dot.